# iPhone High-Res Backgrounds: How to and sources

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

What is the best way to implement a look and feel similar to the PPD Clinical Trials Mobile app (allows search for clinical trials) where it appears they have implemented a UINavigationController and UITabBar controller as overlays over the MainWindow and a high res background.

[image]

Also as a follow up to this question is there anywhere that has some stock iPhone 4 graphics (buttons, icons, and especially backgrounds) that can be used for mocking stuff up?

EDIT 0: By the way, I don't know that they use a UITabBarController for the bottom, but from all indications they do use a UINavigationController up top. It behaves as you would expect.

Comment: In answer to your follow up question you can use [balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/) for mockups - Not free, but totally awesome.  Another good one is [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/), there are plenty of iPhone templates out there on sites like [Graffletopia](http://graffletopia.com/categories/iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the PPD Clinical Trials Mobile app is composed of the following elements:

1. a modal view controller on top of the background;
2. the modal view controller has got a frame smaller than the screen size;
3. the modal view controller contains a UINavigationController;
4. the effect of transparency is obtained by setting the `alpha` property of the views inside the modal view controller to something below 1.0 (which means opaque).

Answer (score 0):

Stock graphics/components:

http://spoiledmilk.dk/blog/iphone-ui-design

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-gui-psd-30/

Icon sets:

http://glyphish.com/

As for the screenshot, I reckon you could accomplish it's contents in the following way:

- Background: Static image, created in Photoshop or similar (pixlr.com as a great free online alternative)
- Navigation bar: Overridden the default UINavigationBar and set the frames of the components differently.
- Selection menus: Overridden default class objects again.

Hope this was of some help!

Comment: I think you understand my question, but what specifically do I do in the CustomNavBar : UINavigationBar that would allow it to be centered and have its width = UITableView below its width? This would help to achieve the PPD app effect.

Comment: Well an instance of UIBarButtonItem has been created and set to self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem for the right button. The left button has been replaced with an image contained within a UIImageView. The text may have just been left aligned, rather than a full rewrite of the navigation bar.